# Newest flash problem

Tags: upgrade, flash

I am using "newest" flash for ubuntu that is 11.2.202.291, but I'm experiencing problems running some flash games/players checking up for newest flash that is currently 11.7.700.224 for windoes. It just says I need to update my flash. Is there any way to skip/lie that I have newest flash installed to run it ?

Im using ubuntu 13.04; 3.8.0-25-generic (64-bit) if that may help in answer somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Google Chrome](https://google.com/chrome) as browser. This has Flash 11.7 built-in.

Yes, 11.7 for Linux, while 11.2 is the "official" latest release for Linux. How? Because Chrome uses the Pepper API for which Adobe is still developing.

As Google mentions on [their support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en):

> Linux users: Adobe Flash Player uses a cross-platform API, [Pepper API](https://developers.google.com/native-client/)
> (PPAPI), to run its plug-in in Chrome. You might notice some of the
> known issues below specific to Linux Chrome:
>
> - Mouse locking may not work.
> - Viewing Adobe Access (DRM) content is not supported, since Adobe does not support it on Linux.
> - Stage3D content will always be rendered through software.
> - Adobe Connect in presenter mode will not work with this version of the Flash Player.
> - Installing Adobe AIR Desktop applications from the web will not work. This includes applications such as Pandora’s Desktop music player, Tweetdeck, Flickr Desktop Search, Twhirl and Amazon’s Music Downloader.
> - Installation of the Octoshape Grid Delivery Enhancement will fail.

This has been announced [in 2010 on the Chromium Blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/03/bringing-improved-support-for-adobe.html). Note that Chromium does not have a bundled version of Flash included (and therefore requires the installation of the 11.2 version).

Example: on `google-chrome-stable` version `28.0.1500.52-r207119`, runs version 11.7.700.203 of Flash as you can see below.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

shows in chrome (chromium web browser) same version (11.2.202.291) as in firefox.

Comment: @Klemik that's because flash only comes built in to chrome, not chromium. therefore, chromium picks up the same (obsolete) npapi version that firefox picks up. there's a way to make chrome's version work with chromium, but i don't know how.

Comment: @Klemik Chromium is not the same as Google Chrome. It's not different in many ways, but certainly for the Flash part, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk thx I didn't know there is chrome linux version (other than chromium). It works like a charm now. Thanks again.